# Why is bright pink background a bad UX/UI?

Tags: design, color

A lot of people commenting on [What color for error messages for a form with a red background?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/94470/what-color-for-error-messages-for-a-form-with-a-red-background) say that bright pink background is a bad UX/UI.

Is it true? Is using bright red/pink as a background automatically a bad decision that results in bad interface and usability? If so, why?

**Note:** if that matters I am not a designer, I only know a little bit of theory here and there, enough to go by for small things I might need.

Comment: Personally (and I'm sure I'm not the alone in this), I associate pure magenta (#FF00FF) with "something is wrong", but that's only from the standpoint of a developer.  Many graphics engines will use that color as a default color for when data is missing, e.g. a 3D model with a missing texture file.  Sure, you could just render it in black or something, but then it wouldn't be as blatantly obvious that there was a missing/broken asset, so magenta is used to stand out better, because it's bright, and less likely to be used legitimately by the artists.

Comment: You have to understand that sometimes people call UI "good or bad" based on trends. UI can not be good or bad without context. A red back ground is totally fine. Red on red is a bad thing. Same as some others.

Comment: I was one of the people who made that comment. My reason was partly that it led to your problem, partly that contrast with white input fields was poor, and partly that I found it dazzling and tiring to look at. In general, I think backgrounds should be subdued colors, so as to not distract form foreground elements. Perhaps it is possible to make bright pink background work, but your question was not an example of this.

Comment: Well, you do run the risk of "magic pink" transparency.  And transparency in UX is so passé.  ;)

Comment: Bright pink background was the default UI for the SGI/Irix operating system. :) Oh, it was one of a kind.

Comment: I voted to close and really should have left a comment. Apologies. One issue is that the question is based on an incorrect interpretation of the original question being asked. The original question was asking about contrast...not a particular color. But beyond that, it's really opinion based and--even if there are objective arguments to be made--what particular color is good/bad is entirely dependent on the *very particular context* the color is being used in. "Is color X bad?" is simply too broad/subjective of a question to have a concrete answer.

Comment: @DA01 The question is not based on an interpretation of the other question but on the statements made by, what I presume, are designers, so I disagree on that part. But I guess the question is too specific to be useful. I was actually thinking about changing it to "Are bright colors a bad choice for a background?" which I believe is useful and can be answered objectively (it pretty much already is) but I don't like altering the question that dramatically after so much time.

Comment: @Maurycy that's the thing, it can't be answered objectively--at least not as a broad statement. While DasBeasto believes they are bad, that's just one opinion (though certainly a valid one) and isn't necessarily based on any particular validated research or science. Without context, it's really hard to make any sort of general statement like 'color X is good/bad for implementation Y'.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this is a UX site. Though there is overlap, you're going to get different types of answers here than if you ask over on, say, GraphicDesign.se.

Comment: @DA01 Even though first half of DasBeasto's answer is indeed missing scientific references, the second part points out a pretty objective (assuming W3S's competency) issue with using bright colors as the background. So there are clearly aspects to this questions that can be objectively answered. Maybe I'm just personally attached to this question but I think there is something good in there. Perhaps "What UX problems bright, saturated website backgrounds have?" would be a better fit? This avoids the subjective and not universally defined "good/bad" classification.

Comment: @Maurycy the second half is about contrast--not any particular colors. It's an important distinction. Contrast is always an issue...be the colors bright or desaturated.

Comment: Agreeing to disagree is exactly my point...it's a matter of pure opinion that bright pink 'hurts' :)

Comment: I guess part of this comes down to the target demographic/intended culture?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**It hurts the eyes**

> Certain colors and color relationships can be eye irritants, cause headaches, and wreak havoc with human vision.
>
> Yellow, pure bright lemon yellow is the most fatiguing color. Why? The answer comes from the physics of light and optics. More light is reflected by bright colors, resulting in excessive stimulation of the eyes. Therefore, yellow is an eye irritant.

and after giving you the task of staring at a red rectangle:

> The 83,000 cones that are used to decode red became fatigued and over stimulated when you focused on the red rectangle.
>
> The operation of the eye is largely muscular and any excessive activity will tire it out.
> http://www.colormatters.com/color-and-vision/color-and-vision-matters

So it is not just the bright pink that is the problem, it is bright colors on the screen in general. Bright colors will hurt a users eyes and cause them to cease using your application sooner.

**Contrast**

There is also the issue of contrast for text on top of it:
[image]

See the pink background example, nearly impossible to read.

> Combinations of colors that are far apart on the visible spectrum require users to constantly refocus their eyes, resulting in visual discomfort and, possibly, fatigue.
> http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2007/01/applying-color-theory-to-digital-displays.php#sthash.NZw9zDUs.dpuf

In fact it is very hard to find a color that contrasts effectively, white and all but the darkest black fail WCAG 2.0 standards for contrast: (showing lightest black that will pass, all *lighter* fail) leaving the most common font colors unusable.
[image]

http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/

Comment: Most of the color combinations in the image cause me almost immediate eye pain though it seems I am more sensitive to those than everyone I know. But why is the strain only limited to colors? After all if red background is straining to the eye than white should be more so, as it contains the whole spectrum and should engage all cones.

Comment: There is a very good answer here http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53264/dark-or-white-color-theme-is-better-for-the-eyes that explains why white is ok. In short it stimulates all three color cones equally making it easier to focus. Very good point though, I'm certainly no scientist so white not being bad does seem confusing to me too.

Comment: This answer makes my eyes hurt :P

Comment: @Devin Right, going through all those articles and toying with the images in paint I now feel the need to take a break from the computer.

Comment: I'm not convinced by some of the arguments here. If yellow is an 'irritant' because it reflects so much light...then white should be even more of an irritant. And we still seem to print on white paper and create web sites with white backgrounds. Regardless, we're talking about an error box...not a book printed on pink.

Comment: That said, contrast is important, of course.

Comment: @DA01 From what I understand it is because white equally stimulates all three cones tightening the iris and allowing you to focus. The link in the comment above tries to explain more. And then of course creating contrast with white is much simpler most of the time.

Comment: @DasBeasto nothing in that article reads with any scientific authority. It sounds more like opinion based ramblings. It *may* have validity, but it's not supported by that article. I also think this falls into the category of "a little data can be more harmful than no data" in that one shouldn't make sweeping UI decisions based on that particular article, IMHO.

Comment: And I just see @Maurycy had the same question! I'd have to argue that the cited article, which itself is lacking citations, simply isn't an authoritative source for this info.

Comment: I remember reading this about 20 years ago (in a physical book in the university library). I recall it because it was interesting, and the choice of colours on my Amiga was (apparently) chosen to ease eye strain. Although I cannot tell you the book, I can confirm this theory of light wavelength affecting the eye focus isn't made up uncited nonsense. That said, I can't say whether its been discredited in the intervening time either!

Comment: @DA01 Perhaps it is just a "best case", white may very well hurt the eyes just provide the best contrast so it is still the best option. I don't think there is any debating that bright colors hurts the eyes and bad contrast provides bad reading so my answer is perfectly valid. This isn't why isn't white bad it is why bright pink/red are.

Comment: @DasBeasto that's exactly what I'm debating: bright colors in an of themselves aren't necessarily good or bad. Context is everything here and though that article may be based on science, it's completely lacking in context of a particular UI. I do agree about contrast and reading text, but that's actually a different topic than what the OP is referring to. Furthermore, that a background is 'bright pink' doesn't say anything about the contrast of the text that may be on it. You could have good contrast and bad contrast...both using a pink background.

Comment: White background is the *least bad* of all the alternatives. (Just like most every decision from many options.) If there was a better option, someone would have found it by now.

Comment: @DA01 You can look at this [fluorescent pink](http://images.labellab.com/img/lg/L/Fluorescent-Pink-Color-Coded-Label-LRect-200-FP.gif) for a full minute and say it doesn't hurt your eyes more than this [oxford blue](https://s.graphiq.com/sites/default/files/2307/media/images/t2/Oxford_Blue_429669_i0.png)? We'll just have to agree to disagree. I agree the article didn't cite it's sources but the fact that bright colors strains eyes is IMO common sense.

Comment: One quibble here: when you say "all but the darkest black", surely you mean various shades of dark grey?  There is only one black, RGB = (0,0,0).

Comment: @jamesqf Yes that was my fault in phrasing, I simply meant that I went to black (0,0,0) and then hit "lighter" until it passed. But of course it was no longer "black" at that point.

Comment: @DasBeasto neither of those squares are 'painful' but you also just put them into very specific context: "Stare at them for a full minute while they are surrounded by a bright white background". We could debate whether that's good or bad, but the point is that the full context of the visual design is the key factor--not the specific color.

Comment: @DA01 I've scaled them to take the full screen to see if not-surrounded by white makes a difference and, actually,the fluorescent pink is much more tiring to look at for me.

Comment: For contrast, `ff29ff` and `000000` pass with normal text at the AAA level.  `ff29ff` looks very pink still.

Comment: "See the pink background example, nearly impossible to read."  What pink background example?  I see red, blue, cyan, purple, yellow and green, but no pink.

Comment: @MasonWheeler the color shown is the hex for [Magenta](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magenta) "Magenta is a color in between red and purple or pink and purple" pink is appropriate just as much as purple. Anyways it's just an example no need to be pedantic.

Comment: @Maurycy that's a fine personal opinion, but by no means a basis for a broad statement that 'bright pink hurts eyes' any more than any other bright color may 'hurt eyes'. It also doesn't mean one shouldn't use bright pink, as it may very well have very useful functionality in a particular context. I can't agree that this answer is entirely 'correct'. In fact, I feel that it's quite misleading.

Comment: The link you are using as citation for your claims does not appear to be serious or authoritative, and I believe the claims made are soundly debunked by modern science. This answer would be far superior if it could cite actual, current research into eye biology rather than peddle the UX equivalent of old wives’ tales. To be clear, I’m not saying that the examples here aren’t bad, they clearly are, but I am not convinced that they are bad *for the reasons this answer claims*, and I’m therefore equally dubious of the generalization from those examples to other cases, such as this question.

Comment: DasBeasto - I think @MasonWheeler has a good point.  Pink and magenta are not the same colour.  The X11 colour code for the name "pink" (as used by web browsers, for example) is #FFC0CB, which is a long way different from #FF00FF.

Comment: I forgot to circle back here back then, but I [asked Skeptics about this idea](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/33091/6207), and while [the only answer I got](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/35782/6207) cites studies that agree that certain colors tire our eyes faster than others, blue and yellow were the primary culprits cited, *not* pink, or bright colors generally. This answer remains unsupported.

Comment: @KRyan In the same paragraph of "book 2" in the answer you linked it says "Pure colors that are highly reflective -- "bright colors" ---are especially taxing, and since they attract the eye, can interfere with work if used within the visual field of the task". And the paragraph before says "To view magenta, a mixture of red and blue, the eye must alternate it's focus rapidly. Magenta, therefore, appears to vibrate, and has a stimulating effect. However, in this case oscillation is much too extreme and can fatigue the eye." So it specifically calls out bright colors and magenta.

Comment: @DasBeasto The snippet I see does not include that information, but very well.

Answer (score 40):

> Is it true?

No.

Nor is it true that it's good UX.

It's a visual design question that can only really be properly answered in context...and part of that would be how it works with the overall page design.

*In the particular context of the cited question...*

[image]

*...it is asking very specifically about **Red** on **Pink***

That's a very specific combination and as DasBeasto states, the issue isn't that one is using red and pink, but rather that there is very little contrast between the red and pink, so it doesn't stand out.

It's an *entirely* different question than the one you are asking, which is if pink, itself, is bad. Again, **no, no particular color is *bad*--but colors can be used in bad ways.**

For example, we can have the same exact problem using green. It's not an issue of color, but of contrast:

[image]

Comment: I was specifically asking about bright pink/red background because I was surprised by the statements in the comments @Andrew linked. Specifically by how broad and unconditional these statements were which in turn made me wonder if those colors are really completely unusable as a background due to some objective reasons.

Comment: Agreed -- poor contrast is the issue rather than the colour choice.

Comment: @Maurycy to be clear, no, there are no blanket objective arguments for not using bright pink.

Comment: But color is linked to contrast.  The human eye has different response levels to R, G, & B— it's most sensitive to green, then red, and least blue.  And technically this is a brightness-sensitivity (rods) concern — instead of a color-sensitivity (cones) one, and the peak of bright-sensitivity is around 500nm (cyan-blue-ish).  So color-wheel-shifting the prev example has left it looking brighter than it was before.  It would've made sense to use the PAL/NTSC grayscale conversion ratios of R=0.299 : G=0.587 : B=0.114 to get a more mid-toned green, but even then the green would be more contrasty.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson I don't think I disagree with any of that.

Answer (score 0):

Any brightly coloured background is a bad UI, for physical and physiological reasons which I expanded on in this answer [Should software for 8 to 14 year olds be colourful and "childish"?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/94278/should-software-for-8-to-14-year-olds-be-colourful-and-childish/94320#94320)

As for how to draw attention to an error message against a pink background: you need to increase the contrast between the red background and the pink background. In @DA01's example above, a white or black border around the red panel containing the error message would help.

But the real problem for me is the bright pink background. Work around it if it's a given that you cannot change, but do not be responsible for choosing it. Pink or red is particularly bad as a background, because chromatic aberration in an eye always forces it forwards from the plane of a neutral screen.